# In TestComplete JScript, how do I release the XMLHTTP object?

Tags: jscript, xmlhttprequest, testcomplete

I am trying to use TestComplete to create an automated test case that will test out the RESTful web services.

Here's the script; I'm using JScript.

```
function test()
{
    var objhttp = Sys.OleObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    objhttp.open("GET", URL_HERE, false);
    objhttp.send();
    // Do stuff with objhttp.responseText here...
}
```

When I run this the first time, it seems to get a correct response and the web service is invoked with no problem. However, the response seems to be cached somewhere after the first run, and when I run the script for the second time, the cached response comes back and it does not seem to invoke the web service at all. So in order to invoke the web service I have to close the TestComplete and then reopen it every time I run the script.

I searched the reference documents and I found out that the OLEObject are not released by TestComplete so I have to release it manually. However, I could not find any method that will release the XMLHTTP Object..

I tried calling abort() or doing delete but they didn't work. How do I solve this??

Answer (score 0):

This is odd behavior and I cannot reproduce it. Everything works fine for me - every time I run this code, it returns a new value:

```
function test()
{
  var objhttp = Sys.OleObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
  var url = "http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new";
  objhttp.open("GET", url, false);
  objhttp.send();
  Log.Message(objhttp.responseText);
}
```

Check how it works for you.